# Facebook photos api: Please reduce the amount of data you're asking

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, multipartform-data

I've setup two business developer applications (test & prod environments) to handle Facebook Login and posting an image to a group directly via a web app. The endpoint I'm using is the following:
[https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{group-id}/photos?access_token={access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/%7Bgroup-id%7D/photos?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

I followed this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/.../refer.../page/photos/...

with a POST request and Content-Type: multipart/form-data.

The request payload looks like the following:

```
-----------------------------41883366036964688284103242839
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png
�PNG
{a bunch of alphanumeric chars........}
-----------------------------41883366036964688284103242839
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="caption"
{the caption of the image}
-----------------------------41883366036964688284103242839--
```

The test environment works flawlessly: I build the picture in javascript and then call the api endpoint against a test facebook group.

On the production environment, the VERY SAME call with the very same image returns the error:

"Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request"

The post actually makes his way on the Facebook group but without the image.

I tried putting the limit=1 param with no luck.

I tried "cross-posting" with the Facebook PROD app to the Facebook TEST group and it works, so it seems the problem is posting to the PROD Facebook group.

In the image below what I see in the browser when the request fails, it seems the image size is below the 4Mb limit given by Facebook. Is there a better way to check the size of the image I'm trying to send?

[image]

However, if the image is the same, how come in one group I get to post correctly and in the other I don't?

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I am working on a similar issue.  If you figured it out that would be great, and if not I can come back here if I do.

Comment: Hi, I did sort it out but believe it or not...I don't know how.
I opened several tickets on facebook developer support channel explaining until one day, magically, it got resolved. My feeling is they did something on their side to enable the group that was causing problem, but I have no confirmation of that.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate.  I was using a URL for the picture but I'm going to try like you did and see if that makes a difference.  Thanks again.